# Startup disk creator will not recognize my iso files, how to I fix this?

Tags: iso, burning, backtrack

I have downloaded the Backtrack 5 R3 ISO (also an Ubuntu Studio 12.10/Ubuntu 12.10 ISOs) and I would like to burn it to a disk (4.7GB DVD-ROM I have) but I can't seem to get Ubuntu to recognize it.

Startup Disk Creator/XFBurn don't recognize it, but they do allow me to load the ISOs into the program, just not burn it to a disk.

I tried burning it with Brasero and after I selected the ISO in the select disk area it said Please replace the disk with a supported CD or DVD I posted the image:

[image]

Comment: use any burner, if the ISO is bootable it will boot. Anyway question regarding unofficial derivative are considered off topic here. Please read [FAQ]

Comment: I thought it was a problem with Ubuntu, as the burner programs don't recognize the disk. The disk just sits there whirring, and program freezes up (I have to kill the process)

Comment: Then you should file a bug report. This is not a normal behavior of ubuntu.

Comment: I wasn't asking about backtrack, I was asking about Startup disk creator/XFBurn not recognizing the DVD-ROM

Comment: Then please edit your question to make it more general and clarify whether it's just the one iso that isn't burning or whether you have the problem with others as well.

Comment: I'd like to know whether Ubuntu recognizes the disk or not. Try burning the DVD with brasero, and please let us know whether brasero recognizes the disk or not.

Comment: I did it and after I selected the ISO in the select disk area it said `Please replace the disk with a supported CD or DVD` I posted the image to my blog, try accessing it here: http://technicalrrr.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/image-burning-setup_001.png

Comment: What type of DVD-ROM are you using?

Comment: It's a Sony DVD-R AccuCore 4.7GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, my drive will NOT recognize blank DVDs (don't as me why), I tested it in Windows and same problem. I will mark this as answer to close the question.